# Chainway C72 Rfid BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, rfid

I have to integrate the **Chainway SDK for RFID** with a **Chainway C72**.

I'm studying their Android example but in the *"Keyboardemulator v11.3.9.M"* app on the device, I can see the setting "BroadcastReceiver" with action "**com.rscja.scanner.action.scanner.RFID**" but if I try to use it, it doesn't work.

Is there a type of setting for the class **RFIDWithUHFUART** to use BroadcastReceiver and not the "onKeyDown()" method?

thanks

Comment: If you use the app Key emulator that comes with the device, you do not need to use the SDK on your application, if your application, the logic when you use the RFID reader is not complex, the key emulator is the best choice, if your logic is more complex and you need more control when you read tags, filtering information and also encoding tags, the best way to go is using the SDK.